# the eigenvalues of sums of two positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

$\mathbf{Question:}$

Let $u_{1},~u_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{6}$ be two orthonormal vectors.

Let $\mathrm{C}_{1},~\mathrm{C}_{2},~\mathrm{C}_{3}$ be three real diagonal matrices with $\mathrm{C}_{1}^{2}+\mathrm{C}_{2}^{2}+\mathrm{C}_{3}^{2}=I_{6}$, where $I_{6}$ is a identity matrix.
Then we can assume that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{C}_{1}&=\mathrm{diag}(\cos a_{1},\cdots,\cos a_{6}),\\
\mathrm{C}_{2}&=\mathrm{diag}(\sin a_{1} \cos b_{1},\cdots,\sin a_{6} \cos b_{6}),\\
\mathrm{C}_{3}&=\mathrm{diag}(\sin a_{1} \sin b_{1},\cdots,\sin a_{6} \sin b_{6}).
\end{align*}

Let $\mathrm{H}_{1}:=\mathrm{C}_{1}
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    u_{1} & u_{2} \\
  \end{array}
\right]$,
$\mathrm{H}_{2}:=\mathrm{C}_{2}
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    u_{1} & u_{2} \\
  \end{array}
\right]$,
$\mathrm{H}_{3}:=\mathrm{C}_{3}
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    u_{1} & u_{2} \\
  \end{array}
\right]$.
Then $\mathrm{H}_{1}^{T}\mathrm{H}_{1}+\mathrm{H}_{2}^{T}\mathrm{H}_{2}+\mathrm{H}_{3}^{T}\mathrm{H}_{3}=I_{2}.$

Let $\alpha_{1}\geq\beta_{1}\geq\gamma_{1}\geq\alpha_{2}\geq\beta_{2}\geq\gamma_{2}$ be the eigenvalues of
$$D=\mathrm{H}_{1}\mathrm{H}^{T}_{1}+\mathrm{H}_{2}\mathrm{H}_{2}^{T}+\mathrm{H}_{3}\mathrm{H}_{3}^{T}.$$

$\mathbf{Prove}$ that the eigenvalues of $D$ satisfy the following inequalities:
$$\alpha_{1}+\beta_{1}+\gamma_{2}\geq1,~\alpha_{1}+\beta_{2}+\gamma_{1}\geq1,~\alpha_{2}+\beta_{1}+\gamma_{1}\geq1.$$

$\mathbf{Idea:}$

Using Proposition 7 in the article ''Eigenvalues, invariant factors, highest weights, and Schubert calculus. Fulton, William. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 37(2000), no.3, 209–249.'',
the necessary conditions about two conditions $\mathrm{H}_{1}^{T}\mathrm{H}_{1}+\mathrm{H}_{2}^{T}\mathrm{H}_{2}+\mathrm{H}_{3}^{T}\mathrm{H}_{3}=I_{2}$,
$D=\mathrm{H}_{1}\mathrm{H}^{T}_{1}+\mathrm{H}_{2}\mathrm{H}_{2}^{T}+\mathrm{H}_{3}\mathrm{H}_{3}^{T}$
are obtained,
but these conditions are not enough to prove the desired result.

Comment: Is there invariant subspaces of D that makes the matrix D block diagonalizable?

Comment: At present, there are only two ideas：1. eigenvalues of sums of Hermitian matrices 2. invariant subspace. 
Let's share your opinions happily.